# Link_to not doing the expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone explain why a Link_to inside a table  should print out the link if the field is null, but print out the field if it contain data(text) in both rails 3 and 2.3.5.

If the field is nul it prints out "/dsplaces/100?country=UK&area=London"

If the field contains data (text) it prints out correctly. The code is:-

```
<td><%= link_to truncate(dsplace.description ,:length => 35), dsplace_path(:id => dsplace.id, :country=> dsplace.country, :area=> dsplace.placename) %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting it to show a link even if the field is empty? That is not at all possible. You should always ensure that the field has content.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was hoping it would not print anything. I will insert an if !=nul or make sure the field is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that by "field" you mean dsplace.description. If you pass an empty string as the first param to link_to, the method will use the url it created as the link's name.

Comment: Thanks Yes I mean dsplace.description and I did not know this, but now I know I will search for other cases and put an if dsplace.description to catch this case.